# how to prove that a numbers value is between 0 and 10

Tags: python

[image: Code which I tried...]

I don't know how to prove that the value of my numbers are between 0 and 10...
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post picture of your code. Instead, please type it into your post. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def check_number(number):
    if (number > 0) and (number < 10):
        return True
    return False
```

or to also include 0 and 10:

```
def check_number(number):
    if (number >= 0) and (number <= 10):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: this can be written as `return 0 <= number <= 10`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if all(0 <= a <= 10 for a in [selected_number1, selected_number2, selected_number3, selected_number4]:
    print('')
    player_number()
```

For the second function

```
if all(0 <= a <= 10 for a in [player_number1, player_number2, player_number3, player_number4]:
    print('')
    check_number()
```

If you want to exclude 0 and 10 then replace `<=` with `<`.